# swap numbers with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to swap numbers with this little python code.

I still don't realize why it gives me `None` when I enter two inputs

```
class numbers:

    def __init__(self, first, second):

        self.first=first
        self.second=second

    def swap(self):

        def swapp(a):
            i=0
            rev=0
            a=int(a)
            while (a>0):

                i=a%10
                a=int(a/10)
                rev=rev*10+i
            return rev

var1=numbers(int(input("num1 \n")),int(input("num2 \n")))


var1_1=numbers.swap(var1)

print(var1_1)
```

Output:

```
num1
5468
num2
625652
None
```

It gives NONE

Comment: `swap` is a function that contains another function, `swapp`.  `swap` doesn't return anything, so `None` is returned implicitly.  `swapp`, the inner function with all the logic, is never executed.

Comment: Editing is on the way.

Comment: you can accept an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
class numbers:

    def __init__(self, first, second):

        self.first=first
        self.second=second

    def swap(self, x):

        def swapp(a):
            i=0
            rev=0
            a=int(a)
            while (a>0):

                i=a%10
                a=int(a/10)
                rev=rev*10+i
            return rev

        return swapp(x)

var1=numbers(int(input("num1 \n")),int(input("num2 \n")))


var1_1=var1.swap(12)

print(var1_1)

>> 21 # i.e. Reverse of 12 meant as an output of swapp method.
```

I believe you tend to utilise it that way. Couple of things wrong with your code. Your `swap()` method doesn't return anything. I assume it needs to call and return you nested `swapp()` method. Your name swap is misleading as actually it is reversing an integer. You can pass a `self` instance as in the above code i.e. the `.` operator not by `var1_1=numbers.swap(var1)`. `Instance.method()` automatically implies the first argument to the method would be `self`. Your `swapp` method needs an argument. A single argument. In my case I passed a constant but you can pass any `instance.variable` like `var1.first` to it.

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: @qräbnö The OP's code gave `None` as the function didn't return anything. As he might be wanting some output from the `swap` method I demonstrated by passing a constant to the `swapp` method

Comment: So the output is `21`? OK, he can go on from here, very well.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler/alternative way:

```
def swap(num):
    return int(str(num)[::-1])

>>> num = 45678
>>> print(swap(num))
87654
```

Explanation:

1. Convert the number to a string. `45678` becomes `'45678'`
2. Reverse the string. A string is a sequence of characters. So, you can slice it just like a `list`. `[::-1]` is the notation used to get a list in reverse. `'45678'` becomes `'87654'`
3. Convert the string back to integer. `'87654'` becomes `87654`

Answer (score 1):

i made works with one variable

```
class numbers:

    def __init__(self, first):

        self.first=first
    def swapp(self):
        a=self.first
        i=0
        rev=0
        while (a>0):

            i=a%10
            a=int(a/10)
            rev=rev*10+i
        return rev




var1=numbers(int(input("num1 \n")))


var1_1=numbers.swapp(var1)

print(var1_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the function swapp(a).